# Open an other form by clicking on a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form which have a button. When I click on it, I want the form that I already coded to be displayed.

I only found that I need to create the form with the code like that :

```
Form forme = new Form();
forme.Show();
```

But it opens a new form and I want to open an existing form.

This code doesn't work :

```
private void buttonPlacer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        creationClasse.Show();
    }
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? Throws exceptions / Form doesn't show?

Comment: sec, What is the creationClasse? Can we see the code for that, and like @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ pointed out, what exceptions does it throw? if any.

Comment: @HyunMi The `creationClasse` is the form that I want to open. I have this error : An object reference is required to access non-static member

Comment: @Erlaunis you might want to read up on OOP if you do not understand what the exception means. MSDN is the goto reference source as usual
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If creationClasse is a class inheriting a Form, you can instantiate it and then show it:

```
creationClasse c = new creationClasse();
c.Show();
```

**Update** - The code above will work.

Comment: But when I create the form like this, it's an empty form which is displayed.

Comment: If it is empty, you will be shown an empty form. What else do you expect?

Comment: I want to display an existing form, not create an empty one :/

Comment: And what is the *existing* form?

Comment: The existing form is "creationClass". I created with some contents like buttons, labels, ...

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ maybe it has already been created.

Comment: @Default If that was the case, then the exception would not have been thrown

Comment: Ok, I understand ! Now, it works with your code ! :) Thanks !

Comment: what exception are you referring to?

Comment: @Default See the **comments** on the question.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I am looking at the question and the comments. nowhere is there a reference to any exception. Would you mind just adding here which exception you mean?

Comment: Third comment. Object reference required to access non-static member

Comment: that's an **error** message, not an exception. That has nothing to do with if a form has been created or not. Sure, removing code which shows an error message and replacing it with other random code solves the initial error message. Doesn't solve the **problem** though.

Comment: @Default Oh yes you are right. Confused it with null reference. But this is not random code. He calls `Show` without creating an instance. And in my answer I provide code for instantiation. I see no wrong in it. And it very much solves the problem/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Form frm = new Form();
void frmShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ( !frm.visible)
     {
        frm.Show();
     }
   else 
     { 
        frm.Show();
     }
}
```